# How to add up values in HTML form inputs with the help Laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, forms, addition

I am trying to get a sum of input values in an HTML form within a Laravel application.
Here is the code that I already have. Any suggestions on how this is possible?

Two Things I want to achieve:

- For "Total Cost" I want it to add up the two dollar amounts of the two inputs and display the sum in the input field.
- For "Total Qty" I want it to add up the two quantity amounts of the two inputs and display the sum in the input field.

```
<!--FORM-->
  <form action="/orders/create" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="productsOrdered">Products Ordered</label>

      <input name="product1" class="form-control" id="product1" placeholder="Product 1">
      <input name="price1" class="form-control" id="price1">
      <select name="q1" class="form-control" id="q1">
          <option value="">Quantity</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
      </select><br>

      <input name="product2" class="form-control" id="product2" placeholder="Product 2">
      <input name="price2" class="form-control" id="price2">
      <select name="q2" class="form-control" id="q2">
          <option value="">Quantity</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
      </select><br>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="shippingcost">Shipping Cost:</label>
      <input name="shipping" class="form-control" id="shipping" placeholder="--.-- (no dollar sign)">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="tax">Tax</label>
      <input name="tax" class="form-control" id="tax" placeholder="(leave blank if 0)">
    </div>


<!--For "Total Cost" I want it to add up the two dollar amounts of the two inputs and display the sum in the input field.-->

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="total">Total Order Cost:</label>
      <input name="total" class="form-control" id="total">
    </div>



<!--For "Total Qty" I want it to add up the two quantity amounts of the two inputs and display the sum in the input field.-->

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="total">Total Qty:</label>
      <input name="total" class="form-control" id="total">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Unfortunately I'm having trouble finding decent documentation/instructions on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the bottom of your code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>

  $("#price2").keyup(function(){
    $("#total").val(parseFloat($("#price2").val()) + parseFloat($('#price1').val()));
  })

  $("#q2").change(function(){
    $("#total_quan").val(parseInt($("#q1").val()) + parseInt($('#q2').val()));
  })

</script>
```

And change the "id" of the quantity total to "total_quan". As a good note, you shouldn't have two elements with the same ID.

Now, this this code I've supplied, this will only work if the first quantity/price is entered followed by the second input. It won't calculate if it's entered as product two then product one. But this should be enough to get you tested and started.

This was all done with jquery/javascript. From here, just send the value of the totals to the laravel back end to do whatever you need to do with the data. So javascript to do the calculations from the form, php to do the server side stuff with the output of the calculations supplied from JS.